# HQL select properties of one entity by joining two tables

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two tables

```
first table (people):id ,name;
second table (relation):id,parent_id,child_id
```

Second table contains parental links between objects from first table. Very simple ))

By this query I get all fields from both tables

```
from People AS people , Relation  as relation WHERE  relation.parent_id=XXX AND people.id=relation.child_id
```

how to get only field from first table?

Comment: In Hibernate the result set is typically modeled after a collection of entities.  Why do you only want certain fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select people from People AS people , Relation  as relation WHERE  relation.parent_id=XXX AND people.id=relation.child_id
```

Comment: Is that a HQL query? And wondering if it is really working and not throwing any Syntax exceptions?

Comment: yes, it's an HQL query. Nothing is wrong with it. See official doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: it's so simple ))